# Infinite waiting on condition variable

Tags: c++, multithreading, deadlock, condition-variable

The simplified goal is to force calling 3 member functions in 3 different threads one by one (thread A calls F::first, thread B F::second, an thread C F::third).

In order to achieve the order for threads to be executed I used 1 condition variable and 2 bools indicating whether first and second threads finished their work.

In the code:

```
std::mutex mtx;
std::condition_variable cv;
bool firstPrinted = false;
bool secondPrinted = false;

class F {
public:    
    void first(std::function<void()> printFirst) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
        std::cout << "first\n";
        printFirst();
        firstPrinted = true;
        cv.notify_one();
    }

    void second(std::function<void()> printSecond) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
        std::cout << "second\n";
        cv.wait(lck, []() { return firstPrinted; });
        printSecond();
        secondPrinted = true;
        cv.notify_one();
    }

    void third(std::function<void()> printThird) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
        std::cout << "third\n";
        cv.wait(lck, []() { return secondPrinted; });
        printThird();
    }
};

auto first = []() {
    std::cout << "1";
};
auto second = []() {
    std::cout << "2";
};
auto third = []() {
    std::cout << "3";
};
F f;
std::thread A(&F::first,  &f, first);
std::thread B(&F::second, &f, second);
std::thread C(&F::third,  &f, third);
A.join(); B.join(); C.join();
```

Now lets consider this situation:

Thread A does not start first - whether the first starting thread was B or C they both block (wait) until get notified (B blocks until notified by A, and C blocks until notified by B)

The infinite waiting (or perhaps deadlock !?) appears when the first starting thread is C, which always yields this output:

```
third
second
first
...and stalling here
```

Theoretically, this should not happen because calling cv.wait in thread C unlocks the mutex which allows thread B to run which in turn also waits (because condition didn't become true) and therefore it unlocks the locked mutex as well allowing thread A to start first which finally should enter critical section and notify B.

1. What is the call path that causes stalling of the program ?
2. What nuance did I miss ?

Please correct me if I was wrong in the thoughts above.

Comment: Have you tried `notify_all`?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux no I haven't, why should I notify_all if only 1 thread waits for a 1 condition ?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux there are no more than 1 thread waiting for a same condition, so I thought `notify_one` would be sufficient

Comment: Don't you have two threads waiting for `cv` ("B" and "C")?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux yes but they wait for different bools to become true

Comment: Ok, but they both wait for `cv` nonetheless. Try it and see if it helps. What happens if "A"'s `notify_one` notifies "C"?

Comment: @ampawd "_yes but they wait for different bools to become true_" The predicate doesn't matter. The `cv` is the same. As the documentation of [`std::condition_variable::notify_one`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/notify_one) states: "_If any threads are waiting on `*this`, calling notify_one unblocks one of the waiting threads._" So one is unblocked, most likely the one you didn't expect (since it isn't specified which one should unblock), calls the predicate, which checks that `bool` is still not set, and then blocks again.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius hmm, this is something I missed I think, however when implementing I was imagining the loop while (!pred()) { wait(); } which tells us that only the unblocking thread will be the only one that waiting for specific predicate to become true

Comment: @ampawd That's the thing. Predicated version of `wait` is implemented in terms of non-predicated, as you show. But `notify_one` just unblocks a `wait` in a single thread.

Comment: FWIW, you maybe have learned something about _how_ to coordinate the activities of different threads when you completed this exercise, but it is a very bad example of _when_ to coordinate. In any real-world program, if you want `first()`, `second()`, and `third()` to be called in that order, then the best way to do it is to call all of them from the same thread. Your goal when writing multi-threaded code should always be to _minimize_ the need for them to communicate with each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`std::condition_variable::notify_one()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/notify_one) will wake *one* of the threads waiting for the `condition_variable`. If multiple threads are waiting, one will be picked. It will wake, reacquire the lock check it's predicate. If that predicate is still `false` it will return to it's waiting state and the notification is in essence lost.

That is what is happening here when the thread running `first` is the last to execute. When it reaches it's `notify_one` there will be two threads waiting for the `condition_variable`. If it notifies the thread running `third`, it's predicate will still return `false`. That thread will wake, fail it's predicate test and return to waiting. Your process now has no running threads and is frozen.

The solution is to use [`std::condition_variable::notify_all()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/notify_all). This function wakes *all* waiting threads who will, one at a time, relock the `mutex` and check their own predicate.